# Spreading data out via Pivot Table in Access VBA

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, pivot

Consider a one-to-many relationship like this:

```
tblStuff
    - id

tblEntry
    - stuff_id
    - the_date
    - the_value
```

With some data like this:

```
stuff_id    the_date      the_value
--------    --------      ---------
42          01-Jan-1920   14
42          08-Jan-1920   12
42          22-Jan-1920   7
99          15-Mar-1920   18
99          22-Mar-1920   17
```

Note that for Stuff #42 there are 2 consecutive entries (1st and 8th Jan), then a week is missed, then another entry.

I need to display each `Stuff` with its entries spread across a specific number of columns, spread out by `the_date`.  For example:

I need to somehow display this like so:

```
id    week1    week2    week3    week4    week5
--    -----    -----    -----    -----    -----
42    14       12                7
99    18       17
```

Is this possible?  The columns represent the number of weeks since the first `Entry`, which may be different for each `Stuff`.  I'm not familiar with pivoting data like this - where should I begin?

Any help very much appreciated.

### EDIT

There is going to be exactly 194 "week" columns.  I'm unable to redesign the database, this is what I have to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Consider building a Weekly Number table which holds each stuff_id weeks starting from first through the 194th week. You can build this in VBA using action queries with passed in parameters in a loop:

```vb
Public Sub WeekNumberTable()
    Dim db As Database
    Dim qdef As QueryDef
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Set db = CurrentDb

    ' MAKE TABLE TO INITIATE FIRST WEEK
    strSQL = "SELECT stuff_ID, Min(the_date) As entry_date,  'week1' As week_number" _
         & " INTO tblEntryWeekNumber" _
         & " FROM tblEntry" _
         & " GROUP BY stuff_ID"

    db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError

    ' PREPARE SQL STRING
    strSQL = "PARAMETERS DayAdd Long, WeekNumber Text(255);" _
        & " INSERT INTO tblEntryWeekNumber (stuff_ID, entry_date, week_number)" _
        & " SELECT stuff_ID, Min(the_date) + [DayAdd], [WeekNumber] As week_number" _
        & " FROM tblEntry" _
        & " GROUP BY stuff_ID"

    ' LOOP THROUGH ALL WEEKS ITERATIVELY FOR EACH STUFF_ID
    For i = 1 To 194
       Set qdef = db.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

       qdef!DayAdd = 7 * i
       qdef!WeekNumber = "week" & i
       qdef.Execute , dbFailOnError
    Next i

    Set qdef = Nothing 
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Once this tabe is build, left join it to original tblEntry data and apply a crosstab query:

```sql
TRANSFORM Sum(t.the_value) AS SumOfthe_value
SELECT w.stuff_id
FROM tblEntryWeekNumber w
LEFT JOIN  tblEntry t ON (w.stuff_id = t.stuff_ID) 
AND (w.entry_date = t.the_date)
GROUP BY w.stuff_id
PIVOT w.week_number;
```

Or in Crosstab Query Design View after left joining tables on *stuff_id* and *the_date*/*entry_date*:

```sql
   Field: stuffId           the_value      weekNumber
   Table: tblWeekNumber     tblEntry       tblWeekNumber
   Total: Group By          Sum            Group By
Crosstab: Row Heading       Value          Column Heading
    Sort:
Criteria:
      or:
```

**Output**

```sql
stuff_id    week1   week2   week3   week4   week5   week6
42             14      12               7       
99             18      17
```

Comment: Wow, thats a great approach!  What do `testValue` and `SumOftestvalue` refer to?

Comment: Whoops! It should have been `the_value`. Copying slip-up. Please try the code routine and tell me if it works for actual use case. I'm curious to hear how it goes.

Comment: I've managed to implement it to the point where I am getting some output, but I don't understand it properly.  First, what is the purpose of summing the values?  Second, the columns output appear ordered as strings rather than their values (eg: `week1`, `week10`, `week100`...)

Comment: Crosstabs transform on aggregated values. Hence, Sum() is used but so can Avg(), Min(), Max() if there is one value per stuff_id per week. And since we concatenate *week*, *week number* becomes a string and sorted as such. Consider using the IN() clause: `PIVOT weekNumber IN ('week1', 'week2', 'week3', ...)` where you can specify ordering, even exclude pivoted columns.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need a [cross tab](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8?ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB&fromAR=1) query.

[image]

I've taken these instructions from the Office support site (link above).  This method uses the query wizard.  Don't worry, it's not as complex as the long instructions would suggest!

> On the Create tab, in the Other group, click Query Wizard.
>
> In the New Query dialog box, click Crosstab Query Wizard, and then
>   click OK.
>
> The Crosstab Query Wizard starts.
>
> On the first page of the wizard, choose the table or query that you
>   want to use to create a crosstab query.
>
> On the next page, choose the field that contains the values that you
>   want to use as row headings.
>
> You can select up to three fields to use as row headings sources, but
>   the fewer row headings you use, the easier your crosstab datasheet
>   will be to read.
>
> If you choose more than one field to supply row headings, the order in
>   which you choose the fields determines the default order in which your
>   results are sorted.
>
> On the next page, choose the field that contains the values that you
>   want to use as column headings.
>
> In general, you should choose a field that contains few values, to
>   help keep your results easy to read. For example, using a field that
>   has only a few possible values (such as gender) might be preferable to
>   using a field that can contain many different values (such as age).
>
> If the field that you choose to use for column headings has the
>   Date/Time data type, the wizard adds a step that lets you specify how
>   to group the dates into intervals, such as months or quarters.
>
> If you choose a Date/Time field for column headings, the next page of
>   the wizard asks you to specify the interval to use to group the dates.
>   You can specify Year, Quarter, Month, Date, or Date/Time. If you do
>   not choose a Date/Time field for column headings, the wizard skips
>   this page.
>
> On the next page, choose a field and a function to use to calculate
>   summary values. The data type of the field that you select determines
>   which functions are available.
>
> On the same page, select or clear the Yes, include row sums check box
>   to include or exclude row sums.
>
> If you include row sums, the crosstab query has an additional row
>   heading that uses the same field and function as the field value.
>   Including a row sum inserts an additional column that summarizes the
>   remaining columns. For example, if your crosstab query calculates
>   average age by location and gender (with gender column headings), the
>   additional column calculates the average age by location, across all
>   genders.
>
> You can change the function that is used to produce row sums by
>   editing the crosstab query in Design view.
>
> On the next page of the wizard, type a name for your query and then
>   specify whether you want to view the results or modify the query
>   design.

You can also manually create these queries using the designer, although I would recommend you use the wizard the first few times.

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA for this. You need a [Crosstab query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-8465b89c-2ff2-4cc8-ba60-2cd8484667e8).

First create a base query from your table, that uses [`DatePart("ww", ...)`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DatePart-Function-26868a79-5505-4e5a-8905-6001372223fa) to calculate the week number, and concatenate it with "week".
Be sure to use the correct arguments for `firstdayofweek` and `firstweekofyear`, depending on your country. In the query you must use the numbers, the constants aren't available there.

If you want 194 week columns, you will also have to add the **year** to that string.

Then run the crosstab wizard on that query.

In the resulting query, switch to SQL view. There you can add

```
PIVOT week_string IN ("week1", "week2", ...)
```

to get all week numbers, even if there is no data for some weeks.
See [TRANSFORM statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208956%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: Yikes, you're right. Good luck @ OP calculating that, but `DatePart("ww", ...` will probably still be involved.